# Editing images containing hidden information

Tags: cryptography, steganography

Suppose we have an image with some hidden info behind it. If we open it in a photo manipulation software like *Photoshop* or *Gimp*, without editing it and just save it as a new image, does the image still contain the secret info?

Comment: Yes or no, depending on how the information is hidden and what format the image is in.

Comment: @MajorMajor What if data is not directly saved by pixels?

Comment: You need to do your home work and [be specific](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise). See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone is hiding a message within an image using [Steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography#Digital), then the message should be unmolested by simply saving it.  Depending on how much the image was modified, and the steganography method used, the message may or may not be readable.

For example if [BPCS-Stenography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BPCS-Steganography) was used to hide the message and you drew a smiley face over the image, then parts of the message will still be readable.  If the message was protected by an [error correcting code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction),  then the original message maybe entirely intact.

**However**,  if you were to take that same image and convert it to a low quality lossy compression scheme like JPEG, then the BPCS-Steganography message will likely be destroyed.